# How to create a list of a list of bits?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of strings. For example, this is a list of two strings.

`["Hello, W", "orld!---"]`.

I already have a function `char2bin` that converts separate string characters characters into a list of binary. Note, this does not work for multiple character strings.
Ex.

```
>>>char2bin('a')
[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]

>>>char2bin('abc')
(ERROR)
```

How would I convert a list of multiple strings into a list of a list of binaries?

For example, `["Hello, W", "orld!---"]`
would result in

`[[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0,1,1,0,1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0,1,1,1,0,1,1, 1]], [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0], [0,1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,0], [0, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 0]]]`

As you can see, each string character has converted into a list of binaries, but since there are two separate strings, there are also two separate lists of binary lists.

Comment: Please share the code you're working with. It will help us understand exactly what's happening

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over the characters in a string, and iterate over the words in a word_list.   So you can do the following :

```
def convert_word(a):
    return [char2bin(x) for x in a]

result = [convert_word(word) for word in word_list]
```

using my own interpretation of char2bin:

```
def char2bin(x):
    return list(bin(ord(x)))[2:]

def convert_word(a):
    return [char2bin(x) for x in a]


word_list = ['abc','bcd']
[convert_word(word) for word in word_list]
```

gives the result:

```
[[['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
  ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
  ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']],
 [['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
  ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'],
  ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']]]
```

which i believe is the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic approaches here, comprehension, functional, and procedural. The comprehension form is considered idiomatic Python (or "pythonic").

#### Comprehension

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) can build the list elements from any Python expression, including other list comprehensions--you can nest them.

`[[char2bin(c) for c in word] for word in ["Hello, W", "orld!---"]]`

The Python comprehension syntax has equivalents of `map()` loops and element `filter()`s without requiring an explicit lambda like those builtin functions would. We don't need filters for this task. But because you already have a function `char2bin()` declared, you can already use `map()` without the lambda, like so.

`[[*map(char2bin, word)] for word in ["Hello, W", "orld!---"]]`

The above version mixes a little functional style into the comprehension, and is probably the most Pythonic.

In Python 2 you wouldn't need to put it in the `[*]` part to make it a list, but in Python 3 `map()` makes a lazy generator instead of a list.

#### Functional

You can always rewrite comprehensions in terms of maps and filters by using lambda (anonymous functions). You usually don't use a lambda in Python when a comprehension would do.

`[*map(lambda word: [*map(char2bin, word)], ["Hello, W", "orld!---"])]`

And the newer unpack-into-list syntax `[*foo]` can still be done with the `list` constructor.

`list(map(lambda word: list(map(char2bin, word), ["Hello, W", "orld!---"]))`

The above is a more functional style, although it could be taken a bit further to point-free style with a functional library using currying and function composition. But even pure-functional languages like Haskell have comprehensions, which is where Python got them from in the first place.

#### Procedural

List comprehensions can always be converted to a procedural-style by using explicit for loops and accumulators (and if-statements when there are filters). This is much more verbose, but would be more familiar to those coming from a procedural language like C, so you still see it pretty often in Python.

```
result = []
for word in ["Hello, W", "orld!---"]:
    binchars = []
    for c in word:
        binchars.append(char2bin(c))
    result.append(binchars)
```

Compare the above to my recommendation:

```
[[*map(char2bin, word)] for word in ["Hello, W", "orld!---"]]
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.